# I was creating a bot to snipe hypixel api discord bot but its creating a error by channel.send_message ,

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
done = default_timer() - START_TIME
if op: 
    winsound.Beep(500, 500) # emits a frequency 500hz, for 500ms
    for result in results:
        profit =  result[1] - result[0][2] 
        print("/viewauction " + str(result[0][0]) + " | Item Name: " + str(result[0][1]) + " | Item price: {:,}".format(result[0][2]) + " | Profit : {:,}".format(profit) + " | Time to refresh AH: " + str(round(done, 2)))
        print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Sniping Auctions :)' + '\x1b[0m')
            
        channel = client.get_channel(954629794224566302)
        channel.send_message("/viewauction " + str(result[0][0]) + " | Item Name: " + str(result[0][1]) + " | Item price: {:,}".format(result[0][2]) + " | Profit : {:,}".format(profit) + " | Time to refresh AH: " + str(round(done, 2)))
```

Comment: Please include more details like the error text, or, if possible, a minimal running example. In this state it is a little hard for someone to help you

Answer (score 0):

This code is not very helpful and provide the error message.

btw `channel.send_message()` is replaced with `channel.send()`